# What does wxScrolled.SetScale() do?

Tags: wxwidgets, wxpython

I am reading the documentation for `wxScrolled`, and came across `wxScrolled.SetScale()`. There is no documentation for it, and calling it seems to have no effect. What does it do?

If it matters, I am using wxPython 4.1.0.

---

In context:

I am writing my own widget subclassing `wxScrolled`. It displays a graph, and I want my user to be able to zoom in and out of the graph. Can I use safely use `wxScrolled.SetScale()` and `GetScaleX()`/`GetScaleY()` to store zoom ratio information?

Comment: are you running on the HiDPI monitor?

Comment: @Igor No, I'm running on a normal 1080p monitor. Does it have something to do with HiDPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale values will be forwarded to [wxDC::SetUserScale()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_d_c.html#a190e43cf66ef402aa67f759d20f22eb0), when `DoPrepareDC()` was called (i.e. you should see their effect if you do your own drawing by overriding `wxScrolled< T >::OnDraw()`).

Probable causes for not having any effect:

- you don't do any drawing;
- custom drawing is done by directly handling `wxEVT_PAINT` and not calling `DoPrepareDC()` explicitly.

Comment: I was using `wxcairo` to do my painting, and created the context before calling `DoPrepareDC()`. This explains it perfectly. Thanks for the quick reply.